# Cant set the Delegate of my UITabbar

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have a simple TabBar-Controller in my Storyboard.
ViewController 1 has a Navigation Controller around itself.
ViewController 2 does not have one.

ViewController 1 is shown first when the App goes up.

i need to implement the following Method:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem(UITabBarItem *)item
```

But i cant set the Delegate of the UITabBar. I Want to set the Deleagte in ViewController 1. In IB i can show the delegate property but i cant draw a line. i tried to set the delegate programmatically. But no matter where i set it, the app always crashes.
So where do i have to set the delegate of my UITabBar ?

Comment: is viewcontroller1 the root controller of the first tab?

Comment: Yes, it is the rootViewController

Answer (score 1):

You should make the App Delegate the delegate of your tab bar. You should be able to drag from the tab bar controller in storyboard to the AppDelegate (maybe file's owner).

In code, you can get a reference to your tab bar controller and set `tbc.delegate = self` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

In both scenarios, make sure to first make the delegate listen to the delegate methods by adding `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` to the interface declaration.

Comment: i checked it again, I cant draw a line in my Storyboard. And i have no Files Owner shown on the left side in my Soryboard file. in my AppDelegate.h i put the line `@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>` and in the .m file i wrote `MyTabBarController *tbc = [MyTabBarController alloc] init];tbc.delegate = self;` And i implementes the Method `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` The app does not crash but no effect

Comment: have you added the tbc as rootviewcontroller to self.window? like self.window.rootviewcontroller = tbc;

Comment: Omg, i made a few changes and now i tried do undo them. Now the line `tbc.delegate = self` shows a warning `AppDelegate.m:18:17: Assigning to 'id<UITabBarControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'AppDelegate *const __strong'`

Comment: In the Storyboard file i can see that the TabViewController is the InitialView, so its the RootViewController, taht is what you mean right?

Comment: `tbc.delegate = self` works again. if i add the line `self.window.rootViewController = tbc;` to the AppDelegate.m i get a black screen and all content has gone.

Comment: Sounds like your tab bar controller is not properly initialized. Check that the right storyboard is selected in the app settings.

Comment: I posted the right solution, to call the delegate-Method. But now theres another mystery. Inside the delegate-Method i call `[self selectedViewController]` and it gives me always the wrong one. It guess it gives me the ViewController wich was previously selected. What is wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this problem. All i did was the following, i created a class for my UITabBarController. I put the Protocol  in to the header file. Switched to the .m and implemented the
`- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` Method.
And that's it. There is no need to set the delegate explicitly.
The delegate-Method is called now.